# No. of times a sub-string occurs in the string

Tags: python, string

**Below is my code:**

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    counter = 0
    for x in range(0,len(string)):
        if string[x]+string[x+1]+string[x+2] == sub_string:
            counter +=1
    return counter
```

When I run the code it throws an error - "**IndexError: string index out of range**"
Please help me in understanding what is wrong with my code and also with the solution.
I am a beginner in Python. Please explain this to me like I am 5.

Comment: Well your index (x) goes from 0 to below the length of the string (the last index). But then you increase it in your if statement, thus going past the length of the string hence the error. If you instead did `for x in range(0, len(string)-2):` it wouldn't happen

Comment: `string[x]+string[x+1]+string[x+2]` is more simply `string[x:x+3]`. But do you really want your function to work only for substrings of length 3?

Comment: Did you succeed? If so, don't forget to close the thread and check an answer by clicking the checkmark to its left

Answer (score 1):

Can't you simple use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) for non-overlapping matches:

```
str.count(substring, [start_index], [end_index])
```

---

```
full_str = 'Test for substring, check for word check'
sub_str = 'check'
print(full_str.count(sub_str))
```

Returns `2`

---

If you have overlapping matches of your substring you could try `re.findall` with a positive lookahead:

```
import re
full_str = 'bobob'
sub_str = 'bob'
print(len(re.findall('(?='+sub_str+')',full_str)))
```

If you got the new [`regex.findall`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module and you want to count as such, try to use the `overlapping` parameter in `re.findall` and set it to `true`:

```
import regex as re
full_str = 'bobob'
sub_str = 'bob'
print(len(re.findall(sub_str, full_str, overlapped=True)))
```

Both options will return: `2`

Comment: So in case you want to do it for the whole string: `string.count(substring, 0, len(string)-1)`

Comment: @Eric, or just leave those parameters out =)

Comment: Good one, forgot about python flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use `count`? It uses way less code. See JvdV's answer. Also, by the way, this is how I can do it:

```
def count_substring(string, substring)
    print(string.count(substring))
```

This simplifies code by a lot and also you could just get rid of the function entirely and do this:

```
print(string.count(substring)) # by the way you have to define string and substring first
```

If you want to include overlapping strings, then do this:

```
def count(string, substring):
    string_size = len(string)
    substring_size = len(substring)
    count = 0
    for i in xrange(0, string_size-substring_size+1):
        if string[ i:i + substring_size] == substring:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

String has built-in method `count` for this purpose.

```
string = 'This is the way to do it.'
string.count('is')

Output: 2
```

Comment: It is the easiest way to count the occurrence of sub-string in a string. So i just thought about giving a simple example to demonstrate how it works. You have answered earlier though. @JvdV